# If the index of infinite series is changed, then the series converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges, show that if $s_i = \sum_{k = i}^{\infty} a_k$ converges for $i >0$, then $s_i \to 0$.

I know that for $s_i = \sum_{k = i}^{\infty} a_k$ to converges, the nth partial sum $s_n = \sum_{k = i}^{n} a_k$ has to converge. I do not understand how to show that $lim$ $s_i =0$. Could someone clarify please?

Comment: If the sum of the series is $S$, then $|s_i|=|S-S_i|$, where $S_i=\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}a_k$. That $|S-S_i|\to 0$ is the Cauchy definition of 'converges' for a series.

Comment: Did you notice that index of the series start at $k=i$?

Comment: Yes, that is why I defined $S_i$ as the sum from $k=1$ up to $k=i-1$. Such that $s_i=S-S_i$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ converges. Then we can say that $L = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}$, and we can make the following claim. 
$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n > N $
$$
\left| L - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_{k} \right| < \epsilon
$$

But:

$$
\left| L - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_{k} \right| = \left| \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_{k} \right| = \left| s_{n} - 0 \right| < \epsilon
$$

which is to say that $s_{n} \rightarrow 0$